# Vitamin B12 deficiency Megaloblastic anemic

Tags: pathology, human-physiology, hematology, nutrition, vitamins

I have two doubts regarding Megaloblastic anemia which shakes my mind

(1) first is- I know that vitamin B12 is required for thymidine synthesis which is further required for DNA synthesis and so if there is vitamin B12 deficiency than the DNA synthesis will get impaired which will affect the progression of cell cycle in the proliferating cells. This is what I know ,, now my question is that if the deficiency interferes with cell cycle progression then how bone marrow hyperplasia can be seen in vit. B12 deficiency??

(2) my second question is that how B12 deficiency interferes with nuclear maturation or rather what actually nuclear maturation is?

What  nuclear maturation signifies ?